# What first name for Brizendine surname is shown in this tax record?

Tags: palaeography, taxation-records, virginia, 1790s

I'm looking at the [Charlotte County Personal Tax records for 1798 (paywalled)](http://www.binnsgenealogy.com/MembersOnlyArea/pdfs/Charlotte/1798PersonalA/04.pdf) as shown in this image:

[image]

I cannot read the first name of the last Brizendine on that page of four of them.  First is [Isaac Brizendine](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Brizendine-22) (his estate), second is [Isaac Junior](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Brizendine-26), third is [Joshua](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Brizendine-42), but the fourth male is unclear to me.  I think it begins with an `I` or a `J` and it appears to be a short name, maybe John?

Here is a close up image of the name:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are right. The fourth name is John Brizendine.

Comment: If the list is alphabetically sorted, it cannot be John.

Comment: @J.J.D. What makes you think the list is alphabetically sorted?

Comment: I started my comment with an 'if'. Since the segment is short and starts with Isaac followed by Joshua, I was wondering.

Comment: Definitely looks like John to me.

Comment: @J.J.D. The Virginia Tax lists are definitely *not* alphabetical.  At most you get sorting by first letter of last name.